# Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add Angular to the functionality of my web application. It's just a simple binding for my App, but it's not working at all. I keep getting this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=EmployeeController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Rb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:19:510)
    at sb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:20:78)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:75:396
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:57:100
    at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at B (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:56:471)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:51:335)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js:51:352)
```

I tried to add reference also to the same project not from CDN and same issue, it tells me that the problem.

Here's my HTML page as well: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fynqjpo3/)

Comment: Add some relevant code

Comment: Why did you post a shortened url?...

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the fact that you're loading AngularJS from a CDN. According to the error, your `EmployeeController` is undefined. Find where you are referencing `EmployeeController` and make sure (1) you're passing the argument correctly and (2) `EmployeeController` is defined before it is referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your controller before you can use it in your markup:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('EmployeeController', function($scope) {
    $scope.person = {
        fullname: "Brittany",
        comments: "My comments"
    }
});
```

[plnkr example](https://jsfiddle.net/fynqjpo3/1/)